# Is it possible to drop data from OLAP database (and to keep definitions)?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, olap, management

[SQL Server Analysis Services from MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard]

Our OLAP DB takes data from OLTP DB. We want to make some changes to its structure and to do this - it would be helpful if we could transfer only current OLAP DB definitions and not data which is "buffered" inside. Then OLAP DB could re-take data from OLTP DB again.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

The easiest way would be to go with Management Studio to the proper SSAS server, right click on the database -> Script Database as -> Create to -> New query window.

That will generate a .XMLA file that creates the complete definition of your SSAS database. That's without the prepared data inside. When you need your database and its data, you just run the XMLA file, it will create the OLAP db, and then Process that database. This will add the data.

But, in theory at least, you should have a Visual Studio project where that SSAS database was created, so if you have it and it's the latest version, than you don't need the OLAP database at all, you just redeploy and process the data.

Comment: Thanks! Our OLAP database is out-of-the-box product - we've got no source project but we've got a "green light" from vendor to customize it. Production server is Standard Edition one. We have to transfer it to Developer or Enterprise Edition. But servers are in different sites, so we have to make DB lighter for transfer time.

Comment: If this helps you, then you can up-vote it (up arrow on left), or even mark it as the answer if it's complete for your problem (V sign near the left arrows) ;).

Comment: Of course. I will.

Comment: But I'm not sure if I could recreate DB from XMLA on Standard Edition. If I cannot save some modifications to OLAP DB (server says it's not supported in Standard Edition) - will I be able to the same with XMLA. We will see.

Comment: From Standard to Enterprise it's supported 100%. The problem is with the other way around.. If there's any problem just post it here, or open a new question regarding the new problem.